# Formula for quadratic equations from Galois theory

Tags: galois-theory

Can we deduce the classical formula for the solutions of a quadratic equations $ax^2+bx+c=0$ using Galois theory?

Comment: I'd be very surprised that its not the case :).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way of deriving the quadratic formula is via the method of Lagrange resolvents, which is an early part of Galois theory (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Other_derivations), under 
Lagrange resolvents).